# Designing graphics on Android

Tags: android, image, icons

Can anyone suggest what software or tools that the best to design icon and images for Android?

Comment: I can't see how this question is in any way Android-related. Or programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Android Asset Studio http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html which you can use with your graphics images. Those graphics images of yours you can create using your favorite editor such as Gimp or maybe Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image editing tool such as Photoshop, Gimp, Paint.Net, even MS Paint! I personally use Paint.Net, a free and simple to use image editor.